# Top bar not rescalling when making window smaller(HTML,CSS)

Tags: html, css, web

Hello guys i am working on this website, but i have a problem with my top bar cause it doesn't rescale when i make the browser window smaller. I have tried searching on various website for more solutions but didn't find any. Your help would be appreciated.

Here is my code :

HTML

```
         <div class="main">
            <div class ="centering">
                <a href="index.html" >Home</a>
            </div>
            <div class="aboutbutton">   
                <a href="About.html">About Me</a>
            </div>
            <div class="portfoliobutton">   
                <a href="Portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
            </div>          
            <div class="whatforyoubutton">
                <a href="What can i do for you?">What can i do for you?</a>         
            </div>
            <div class="contactbutton"> 
                <a href="Contact.html">Contact</a> 
            </div>      
        </div>
```

And this is the CSS :

```
            .centering{
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:-8px;
            margin-left:50px;
            margin-right:1050px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-radius:3px;
            color:white;
            font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#2B2930;
            position:relative;
            display:block;
            }

            .aboutbutton{
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:-29px;
            margin-left:293px;
            margin-right:750px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-radius:3px;
            color:white;
            font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#2B2930;
            }

            .portfoliobutton{
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:-29px;
            margin-left:593px;
            margin-right:500px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-radius:3px;
            color:white;
            font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#2B2930;
            }

            .whatforyoubutton{
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:-29px;
            margin-left:843px;
            margin-right:200px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-radius:3px;
            color:white;
            font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#2B2930;
            }

            .contactbutton{
            text-align:center;
            margin-top:-29px;
            margin-left:1143px;
            margin-right:50px;
            border-style:solid;
            border-width:1px;
            border-color:#000000;
            border-radius:3px;
            color:white;
            font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
            font-size: 20px;
            font-weight:bold;
            background-color:#2B2930;
            }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've put together a much neater version of what you have here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ncp24/ Can you explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: Why on earth are you positioning your buttons with those crazy margins?

Comment: @Askanison4 That's much better, but since it's a nav, it should probably be an un-ordered list, rather than multiple divs.

Comment: @NickR oh, absolutely. But I am not going to determine the OPs intentions, just fix what was broken :)

Comment: :) cool - http://jsfiddle.net/Ncp24/4/

Comment: @Askanison4 thanks for you answer it helped a bit, still i have some questions, how do i make the space between each element 0px?? cause there is a light distance and that doesnt make it look to good. What i am trying to achieve? well you know when you try to make the window smaller from the right bottom corner you expect your page to shrink with it. now what i have with your example is that if i shrink it to the maximum the div elements get one below another. i want it to be static

Comment: @NickR pardon my lack of knowledge mate buy this is the first time i make a website without taking code from the net, so this is what my knowledge has written down hehe, thanks for commenting though :)

Comment: Any idea how i can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try out this JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ncp24/1/

You can use
`margin: 0 auto;` and `width: 50%;` as I have in the example to achieve the effect you want.

Here's an updated version without hard coding the width courtesy of Paulie_D: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/Ncp24/3

Comment: @Paulie_D Oh I like that. Great example. Mind if I update it into the post?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to look a little into responsive web design to be able to do this. you can make divs rescale by using percentages here is a link to some code i made previously you can use and make your own. also link to js fiddle file http://jsfiddle.net/ThCcd/

```
HTML
<body class="body">
<div class="mainContent">
<div class="Content">
<div class="topContent">
<div class="mainHeader">
<div id="nav">
<div align="center"><!--nav start-->    
<div id="nav"><a href="#"><b>Contact Us</b></a></div>
<div id="nav"><a href="#"><b>Ebay</b></a></div>
<div id="nav"><a href="#"><b>Team</b></a></div> 
<div id="nav"><a href="#"><b>Facebook</b></a></div>   
</div><!--end nav-->


CSS
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

*{
text-decoration:none;
}
body{
font-size:87.5%; /*Normal font 14px */
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
line-height:1.5;
text-align:left;
}
.body {
margin:0 auto;
width:70%;
clear:both;
}

#wrapper
{
width:100%;
margin:0 auto;
}

#nav{
background-color:#EEECED;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
-moz-opacity: 0.75;
opacity: 0.75;
-ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha"(Opacity=75);
}
.topContent{
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
padding:3% 5%;
margin-top:2%;
background-image:url(paper.jpg)
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation : landscape)
and (orientation : portrait)
{

.body {
width:90%;
font-size:95%;
}
.topContent{
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
padding:3% 5%;
margin-top:2%;
margin-bottom:4%;
}
}
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape)
and (orientation : portrait)
{
.body {
width:90%;
font-size:95%;
}

.topContent{
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
padding:3% 5%;
margin-top:2%;
margin-bottom:4%;
}
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation : landscape)
and (orientation : portrait)
{

.body {
width:90%;
font-size:95%;
}



.topContent{
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
padding:3% 5%;
margin-top:2%;
margin-bottom:4%;
}
}

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px)
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
and (orientation : landscape)
and (orientation : portrait)
{

.topContent{
background-color:#FFF;
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
padding:3% 5%;
margin-top:2%;
margin-bottom:4%;
}
}
```

Comment: sorry its a little messy